# Download audio from Firebase storage

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to create a voice messaging android app using firebase storage as backend, but i'm having issue while downloading mp3 file while it uploads successfully.

Can somebody please provide simple code just to download an audio file from storage.
I'm new at android development , so sorry for being noob

i've added all the permissions in my manifest file like bellow

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Tis is my uploading code

```
private void uploadAudio() {
    pd=new ProgressDialog(this);
    pd.setMessage("Uploading");
   pd.show();
    StorageReference filepath = mstorage.child("Audio").child("New_Audio");
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(mFileName));
    filepath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
          pd.dismiss();


        }
    });
}
```

And for downloading

```
private void startdownload() {

    down = mstorage.child("Audio/");

    File localFile = null;
    try {
        localFile = File.createTempFile("Audio", "mp3");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    down.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Downloded",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: what's the problem/error? the reference `down = mstorage.child("Audio/");` is not pointing to a file, should be something like `Audio/theaudiofile.mp3`

Comment: it gives the storge error like "StorageException has occurred.Object does not exist at location.Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404"

and yes i've provided the proper path to the file like Audio/New_Audio.mp3  but it still gives storage exception

Comment: make sure that the file exists in the Firebase Storage, you can check it via the console.

Comment: yes. the file exists already, its the same file i'm trying to download which i uploaded through upload method. but it still gives the same exception and i'm stuck at this error for last 3 days :(

Comment: hmm weird, hope someone could answer your question. my last attempt, try changing your StorageReference for upload to `StorageReference filepath = mstorage.child("Audio").child("New_Audio.mp3");` and for download `down = mstorage.child("Audio").child("New_Audio.mp3");`

Comment: Yes it worked this time, my Toast shows file downloaded.
But i cant access that temporary file created in internal storage, using phone. is there any cache folder or what. 
i really apericiate you response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your StorageReference for the upload and download method is the same.

```
//upload
StorageReference filepath = mstorage.child("Audio").child("New_Audio.mp3");
//download
down = mstorage.child("Audio").child("New_Audio.mp3");
```

To save the file in the external storage, you can follow [this Android Developers guide](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html)

An example:

```
try {
    File localFile  = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "New_Audio.mp3");
    localFile .createNewFile();
    down.getFile(localFile);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Downloading use :

```
down = mstorage.child("Audio").child("New_Audio.mp3");
```

Once the file is downloaded you can check the file path by

```
localFile.getAbsolutePath();
```

Make a Toast of it, Like this :

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), localFile.getAbsolutePath(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

I hope You got my point :)