# How to send mp3 files to firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

I want to send mp3 files to firebase storage but my code is not working. I don't have an error. it just doesn't work.

I want to upload the sound file I selected from my phone to firebase storage.

here is my code:

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RQS_OPEN_AUDIO_MP3 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if ((data != null) && (data.getData() != null)) {
            Uri mp3FileUri = data.getData();

            Toast.makeText(sesyolla.this, "OKAY", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            info.setText(mp3FileUri.getPath());
        }

    }
}


 private void uploadFile() {
    if (mp3FileUri != null) {
        final StorageReference fileReference = mStorageRef.child(System.currentTimeMillis()
                + "." + getFileExtension(mp3FileUri));

        fileReference.putFile(mp3FileUri).continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
            @Override
            public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    throw task.getException();
                }
                return fileReference.getDownloadUrl();
            }
        }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                    Log.e(TAG, "then: " + downloadUri.toString());


                    Upload upload = new Upload(edittext.getText().toString().trim(),
                            downloadUri.toString());

                    mDatabaseRef.push().setValue(upload);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(sesyolla.this, "upload failed: " + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }


}
```

Comment: Have you tried this, this may help you (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39180901/download-audio-from-firebase-storage)

Comment: @unzila That's not accurate. Firebase [Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage) can store a wide variety of files including images, videos and audio files; and there's no reason to split up the files. Also, the OP is asking about mp3, not images. To the OP, please do some troubleshooting before posting. You can step through you code and examine variables to see which ones are not what you expect - then update your question. Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Full solution:**

CloudStorageDatabaseUtils.java

```
 public class CloudStorageDatabaseUtils {

        public void uploadImage(String storageChildAndPath, File file) {

            Uri uriFile = Uri.fromFile(file);

            StorageReference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
            final StorageReference ref = storageRef.child(storageChildAndPath);

            ref.putFile(uriFile);

        }

        public void getDownloadURL(String path, UrlReceiver receiver) {

            StorageReference reference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child(path);

            reference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(uri -> receiver.onUrlReceived(uri.toString()));
        }
    }
```

activity_upload_image.xml
just a button

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_upload"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="@string/action_upload_an_image"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

UrlReceiver.java

```
public interface UrlReceiver {
    /**
     * @param url URL which will be received
     */
    void onUrlReceived(String url);
}
```

UploadImageActivity.java

```
public class UploadImageActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, UrlReceiver {

    CloudStorageDatabaseUtils databaseUtils = new CloudStorageDatabaseUtils();
    String downloadUrl;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload_image);
        Button upload = findViewById(R.id.button_upload);

        upload.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button_upload:
                File rootStorage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                File exactlyFile = new File(rootStorage.toString() + "/download/q1.jpeg");//or whatever

                databaseUtils.uploadImage("/example1/" + exactlyFile.getName(), exactlyFile);
                databaseUtils.getDownloadURL("/example1/" + exactlyFile.getName(), this);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUrlReceived(String url) {
        if (url != null) {
            downloadUrl = url;
            Log.d("MyS", "url: " + url);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm new to Android. I don’t know how to use uploadImage() method inside button to send audio file.

Comment: uploadImage() this is just example ^_^ You can upload any file. Next. I'll change answer, just wait... I'll explain you everything

Comment: If you're using an Android SDK >= 23, then you need to ask a permission at runtime (even if you have already added it to Manifest), consider it too

Comment: Also, I forgot to say you that the Logcat can tell you a lot of useful things, such as 'I can't find file because you don't have permissions\that file\sdcard and etc.

Comment: I've been trying for hours, but it didn't. I select the mp3 file from my phone.
but I can't transfer firebase. Would you recommend a source?

Comment: Okay, maybe, we need logcat? Make a sreenshot and load it in the main question.

Comment: And what does take mp3FileUri?

Comment: mp3FileUri is the audio file I selected from my phone. I think the problem is mp3FileUri is empty. I don't have a Logcat error. but when I get home, I can send them all.

Comment: Good. Use breackpoints if you are not clearly sure about emptyness of any variable